# Solving an ODE numerically with different units

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, units

I am simulating a [leaky integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_neuron_model#Leaky_integrate-and-fire) with $R_m = 10^8 \, \mathrm{\Omega}$ and $C_m = 10^{-10} \, \mathrm{F}$ with an input current of $I_{in} = 10^{-9} \, \mathrm{A}$ for $0.1 \, \mathrm{s}$:

$$C_m \frac{\mathrm{d}V_m}{\mathrm{d}t} = I_{in} - \frac{V_m - V_{rest}}{R_m}$$

However, I would like to measure time in $\mathrm{ms}$. I thought because

$$\mathrm{\Omega = \frac{kg \, m^2}{A^2 \, s^3} \qquad F = \frac{A^2 \, s^4}{kg \, m^2} \qquad s = 1000 \, ms}$$

the new values of $R_m$ and $C_m$ should be $0.1 \, \mathrm{\Omega}$ and $100 \, \mathrm{F}$ and I do get the same result, but only if $I_{in} = 1 \, \mathrm{A}$ now. This does not make sense to me, because the unit of $I_{in}$ is not time-dependent. What am I missing?

---

*short answer:*
My scalings are correct, but when I numerically integrate $V_m$
`Vm[i+1] = Vm[i] + dt / Cm * (Iin[i] - (Vm[i] - V_rest) / Rm)`
because `dt / Cm` gets scaled by $10^{-9}$ I have to scale $I_{in}$ by $10^9$ to get the same result.

Another way to see this is that $I_{in}$ gets scaled because $R$ is scaled and $I = \frac{V}{R}$.

Comment: Is the Python code relevant to the problem?  It doesn't seem to be, so you should remove it to make your question more focused. If it is relevant, you should post it on the computational science site and not here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the units by scaling, we generally want to write our formulae as a unitless number (which is what changes in the simulation) and a constant unit scale (which does have to be consistent across the whole equation, they cannot be individually arbitrary); e.g. $V=\nu v$ where $v$ is unitless and $\nu$ our unit. This would give,
$$ \gamma c_m \frac{\mathrm d\nu v_m}{\mathrm d(\tau T)} = \iota i_{in} - \frac{\nu v_m - \nu v_{rest}}{\rho r_m} $$

So I think that what you're missing is that you have a $\mathrm dt$ term on the left side that changes scales, meaning both terms on the right ought to change also. We can move the scales from the left side to the right to give,
$$ c_m\frac{\mathrm dv_m}{\mathrm dT}=\left(\frac{\iota\tau}{\gamma\nu}\right) i_{in}-\left(\frac{\tau}{\rho\gamma}\right)\frac{v_m-v_{rest}}{r_m}, $$
which might make it more clear about the scaling of the current.

You may want to read through Wikipedia's entry on [*nondimensionalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) for more discussion on this subject.

Comment: I think this approach is promising, but if $\gamma$ changes by $10^{12}$ and $\tau$ by $10^3$ ($\iota$ and $\nu$ unchanged) the factor in front of $i_{in}$ gets scaled by $10^{-9}$ instead of $10^9$. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, that does appear correct.